# my custom search doesn't properly name result links. How can I control this process?

Tags: javascript, html, google-search

On site I have articles. So when I search Articles I ger links that work ok , u press the link and an article opens.
But before pressing the link, when u look at it u don't see name of the article, instead u see "login, forgot password" etc... text which google search takes from the main page of my site, instead of taking articles name.

Maybe I set up my links somehow wrong so google search tryies to find some text and goes there in the beginning of my site. Anyway....

Is there a way to fix it, or how can I control it, or what are the rules of naming links? Do I have to have some speciall attribute in my links tag ?

instead of making `<a href='mysite.com?index.php?a=some_airticle'>some_article</a>`

google search does the following

```
<a href='mysite.com?index.php?a=some_airticle'>login...forgot password... register....</a>
```

"login...forgot password... register...."
That text is mine it is located at the beginning of my site.

Comment: Have you tried using google webmaster tools: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en perhaps you are missing title tags or meta tags?

Comment: can you tell me where should I have these title and meta tags ?

Comment: In the head of your html

Comment: I do have it. I put "TEST" in title so every page of my site has TEST Title now but still now luck with google search

Comment: Well... with search engines you have to give it a while for it to reindex your site

Comment: ok I'll wait for tomorrow probably, let's see what happens. All links have Title='TEST'